# What is the difference between formControl.hasError('required') and formControl.errors?.['required']

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a reactive form in Angular. I have seen the both approach in forums. Some say that we should avoid function calls in the template. So what is the difference and which is the best practice?

```
<mat-error *ngIf="foundingYear?.hasError('required')">Founding Year is required</mat-error>
<mat-error *ngIf="foundingYear?.errors?.['required']">Founding Year is required</mat-error>
```

in the component:

```
get foundingYear() {
    return this.teamForm.get('foundingYear');
  }
```

Comment: Both are valid. `foundingYear.hasError('required')` is much more readable.

Comment: You can reach the same solution without any function call or one or more function calls `this.teamForm.get('foundingYear').hasError('required');` or 
`this.teamForm.controls['foundingYear'].errors?.['required'];`

Comment: Of course, but one is immediately obvious as to what the intent is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its up with what your intent,
Normally, for me I use `hasError` for specific case and `error` of generic case.
eg.

```
 <div *ngIf="foundingYear?.errors">
      <mat-error *ngIf="foundingYear?.hasError('required')">Founding Year is required</mat-error>
      <mat-error *ngIf="foundingYear?.hasError('limit')">Founding Year is not lower than 1999</mat-error>
 </div>
```

Alternative for my daily code

**.html**

```
 <div *ngIf="foundingYear?.errors">
      <mat-error *ngIf="hasError(foundingYear, 'required')">Founding Year is required</mat-error>
      <mat-error *ngIf="hasError(foundingYear, 'limit')">Founding Year is not lower than 1999</mat-error>
      <mat-error *ngIf="hasError(foundingYear, 'onlyNumber', 'notStartWithZero')">Got wrong format</mat-error>
 </div>
```

**.ts**

```
isError(abControl: AbstractControl, ...error: string[]): boolean {
    let isErr = false;

    error.forEach((err) => {
      isErr = isErr || abControl.errors?.[err];
    });

    return isErr;
}
```

Hope this help.